# MATLAB: ODE45 time dependent paramters in R14SP3 and interpolation issue

Tags: matlab

In [how-do-i-solve-an-ode-with-time-dependent-parameters-in-matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97074-how-do-i-solve-an-ode-with-time-dependent-parameters-in-matlab)

Q: *Consider the following ODE with time-dependent parameters:
 `y'(t) + f(t)y(t) = g(t)`
and the given initial condition:
 `y(0) = 1`
This is an example of an ODE with time-dependent terms. Suppose the time-dependent terms are defined only through the set of data points given in two vectors. Which of the MATLAB ODE solvers should I use, and how do I set up this problem?*

A: *This enhancement has been incorporated in **Release 14 Service Pack 3 (R14SP3)**. For previous product releases, read below for any possible workarounds*

My question one is: I use Release 14 Service Pack 3 (R14SP3) indeed. But the answer does not mention how to deal with it. How can I implement time dependent parameters in ODE45?

My question two is: Because I do not know how to implement time dependent parameters in ODE45 in (R14SP3). I plan to use the old method of interpolation in the answer of that page. But why do we need interpolation as we already know the **exact** form of time-dependent parameters.

My question three is: Jan Simon in the comment points out its flaw of interpolation. I have implemented the method suggested by Jan Simon using "integration per loop". But Jan Simon's method treat the variable as constant inside ODE45. So How to do integration inside the ode45 "h" intervals as well? I know how to do integration in my defined interval, but the ode45 will treat the variable as constant when running its own intervals. For example, doing integration per loop for each timestep:

```
function Integrationperloop
tResult = [];
xResult = [];
tStep = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11];
x0    = [1 2 3];
for index = 2:numel(tStep)
  % Integrate:
  beta = 1 + exp(-0.20*tStep(index - 1))
  af   = @(t,x) f(t, x, beta);
  t    = tStep(index-1:index);
  [t, x] = ode45(af, t, x0);
    % Collect the results:
    tResult = cat(1, tResult, t);
    xResult = cat(1, xResult, x);
    % Final value of x is initial value for next step:
    x0 = x(end, :);
  end
%This is the derivative
function dx = f(t,x, beta)
dx = [-0.5*x(1)-beta*x(1)*x(3); ...
      beta*x(1)*x(3) - x(2); ...
      x(2) - x(3)];
```

However in the code above ode45 will treat the variable as constant when running its own intervals. In the link [how-do-i-solve-an-ode-with-time-dependent-parameters-in-matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97074-how-do-i-solve-an-ode-with-time-dependent-parameters-in-matlab), MathWorks Support Team suggest using the enhancement in R14S13 or using interpolation. If using interpolation, when ODE45 is running the time-dependent variable changes using interpolation.

Comment: Wow R14SP3 is a *very* old version of Matlab! 2005 I think. Please edit your question to provide code for what you've tried so far. Then we can try to determine what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @horchler My version is beyond R14SP3 I think. It is MATLAB 2015a. My actual code is quite complicated and long but I will try to provide a simplified version.

Comment: @horchler Can you give me some hints on solving Time dependent Schrodinger equation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981618/solving-time-dependent-schrodinger-equation-using-matlab-ode45